# Can the GUI be scaled down in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-interface, dpi

In Windows 7 there is the ability to scale the GUI size up by going to Control Panel -> Personalize -> Set custom text size.  However, there is no obvious way to set the zoom to anything below 100%.  I come from linux, so I'm used to being able to make the interface smaller.  Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup custom DPI below 100% on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use DPI settings below 96 (100%), start the Registry Editor (backup your registry first) and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts`

**LogPixels** value is 96 decimal.

For 90 percent font size, set to 86 decimal.

For 80 percent font size, set to 76 decimal.

Close REGEDIT and reboot the computer.

If some text appears too small or blurry try different value or return to 96 dpi.

*Source: [Vista less than 96 DPI by registry change](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-12843-0.html?forumID=102&threadID=269119&messageID=3190792) (works for Windows 7)*