# Windows zoom issue

Tags: windows-8.1, zoom

My friend accidentally zoomed in too much on a Windows computer.

He did this:
1. Search text size
2. Go to the first option
3. Change the text size to 500%

Now everything on his screen is too big.

How can he change it back?

Comment: Registry location is shown in this question http://superuser.com/questions/84386/can-the-gui-be-scaled-down-in-windows-7/84399?s=1|0.8568#84399 A batch could be used to import, then reboot. You could also restore the registry that is being backed-up  constant by the windows system, as that stores the change.

Comment: Why can't he undo whatever he did the same way? By moving the windows around he should be able to see the controls and revert back to the previous settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+ scroll with the mouse wheel. Usually scrolling the top of the mouse wheel makes things zoom out. It wil be easy to see which way makes things smaller .

Comment: That works only in browsers. My friend zoomed his whole computer.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to reduce the magnifier, if that's what is causing the problem