# Why RegEdit does not save my changes?

Tags: display, windows-8.1, fonts, regedit, dpi

I have a windows 8.1 and my target was to decrease screen DPI from 100%  down to 80%.
Or from 96 down to 76.
I found some kind of solutions from internet which tells me that, that kind of job can be done using RegEdit!

[How to setup custom DPI below 100% on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7)
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/large-fonts-registry-exactly-t2695627.html

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI\LogPixels - 0x60
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current\Software\Fonts\LogPixels - 0x60

But when I change those numbers from 96 down to 76 and then I restart the system, it does not effect the screen size...
I mean when I will check that number in RegEdit it will again 96 not 76! And I don't know why?
So what should I do?
How can I reduce that DPI?

Also in this location there is not a "DWORD (32-bit) Value" called "LogPixels"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop"
Should I create it manually?
Even if I will, it will not work!

Answer (score 0):

The key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels` appears to be the one that changes when you adjust the text size from the Control Panel.
It also appears to be mirrored at `HKEY_USERS\[current user definition]\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels`

Try those... at your own risk, I've not tested the actual result of dropping the font size below 96

Sorry, I missed a bit... Re: "Also in this location there is not a "DWORD (32-bit) Value" called "LogPixels"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" Should I create it manually?"

... Try changing your text size via the regular control panel to 125 or 150 & see if it adds the key, otherwise, add it yourself [previous caveats apply]