# How to correctly reset Windows 7 screen DPI back to normal (Smaller 100%)?

Tags: windows-7, display, fonts, display-settings, dpi

Using the control panel `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display` (partly displayed in the screenshot below), I first changed the DPI from the "Smaller 100%" setting to the "Medium 125%" setting, and after a few days back again to the "Smaller 100%" setting. However, not everything is back to its normal size.

In particular, some applications, e.g. Chrome, now have very small text in some parts, smaller than it was with "Smaller 100%" setting before.

[image]

In the screenshot above, the Chrome window in the back is running in a Remote Desktop session, and here the title in the Super User tab is the expected size. Next to it is an instance of Chrome from my desktop, where the title in the Super User tab is clearly smaller.

I have checked the registry and all 'LogPixels' are set to 96, the [fix mentioned elsewhere on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7?rq=1) does not seem to apply.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you rebooted since changing the setting?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, hehe yes, I appreciate the default tech support advice :) Its been a while since I tried resetting back to "Smaller", now I just wanted to see if there was a fix for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that changing the DPI setting in Windows 7 also changes some font settings deep in Windows 7's "Window Color and Appearance" control panel found via `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance`, followed by a click to "Advanced appearance settings...".

Anyway, the easy solution in my case was to reset back to the Aero Theme "Windows 7" in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization`, and after a reboot, everything is back to normal.