# How do I zoom up to 52000% on Microsoft Visio? (I used to be able to do that)

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2003

I've been using Microsoft Visio Professional 2003 for ages now, since it is wonderful and allows me to do everything that I need for designing my solar photovoltaic rooftop designs for our installers and electricians.

I have been able to zoom up to 52000% on my drawings within the program, which was amazing, for the past 4 years of using this program.

Recently my company updated our office servers and our Microsoft programs/ Outlook email were all updated to Microsoft 2016. Anyway, I had to re-download my Visio Professional 2003 program on my computer, since I have the physical CD/case, so it all works now still, but **now I can only zoom up 3098%.**

I tried looking everywhere online and in the help section on Visio, but there is nothing about how much one can actually zoom in or how to manually change the amount of zooming that one can do.

**Q:** Any thoughts or help on how i can zoom up to 52000% again?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running?

Comment: I'm curious what the use-case is for zooming in 52000%? Are you trying to see the electrons in the PVCs?

Answer (score 22):

According to an old MSDN article, the max zoom is dependent on the page size and screen DPI (see below).

> [How Far Can I Zoom In? - Visio Insights](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2006/09/12/how-far-can-i-zoom-in/) 
>   September 12, 2006
>
> To calculate the maximum zoom level, Visio uses this basic formula:
>
> > Max Zoom = (32767 / (Page size in inches * Screen pixels per inch)) *
> >     100%

This formula works for me with Windows 7 and Visio 2010.

Max zoom = (32767 / (96 dpi * 11 inches)) * 100% = 3103% (close to 3098%)

**Summary:** To allow a higher zoom, either lower your font DPI or use a smaller page size.  **Font DPI is not affected by resolution or monitor dimensions.**

**Note:** To force a DPI below 96 (100%), see this post: [How to setup custom DPI below 100% on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7)