# Reduce the font size windows 10

Tags: windows, dpi, scaling

I have been trying to reduce the font size of my PC. However in *Display Settings* there is option to increase the font size to 125% but no option to reduce it to 75%.

Here is the screenshot.

[image: Scrrenshot]

Also is it possible to reduce the dpi ?

Comment: [DPI Scalling Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1213201/241386)

Answer (score 1):

100% is the lowest resolution option, Microsoft probably restricted it likely because settings less than 100% may break text rendering in some software. Look at this case below.

How to setup custom DPI below 100% on Windows 7?

[How to setup custom DPI below 100% on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7)